# Computer turns on but windows don't boot, this happens several times before really booting

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I'm having a huge problem with my machine.  Windows is working normally, but when I turn the computer off and back on again, it take several attempts until it finally boots the Windows OS.  When it fails, nothing really happens:  no noise, the screen stays black, and only the keyboard lights turn on.  I don't believe this is a problem with the RAM, hard drive or CPU... could it be battery issues?

I already re-install Windows using a bootable pen drive hoping to fix it, but that didn't work.

UPDATE ---

Just to be clear, the machine turns off automatically after attempting to boot, so I need to try I don't know... 20 times until it finally works? I'm afraid of damaging my hardware.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Remove All RAM items and run the PC if you hear a Long Buzz sound(depending on existence of motherboard's speaker) then try the following :

- clean the RAM slot
- Try only one RAM item if you have multiple RAMs
- If it works add more RAMs

if you don't hear the long Buzz sound then try cleaning the processor .